# Passing a Block to a delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, delayed-job

I have a function that is marked to be handled asynchronously by delayed_job:

```
class CapJobs
  def execute(params, id)
    begin
      unless Rails.env == "test"
        Capistrano::CLI.parse(params).execute!
      end
    rescue
      site = Site.find(id)
      site.records.create!(:date => DateTime.now, :action => "Task Failure: #{params[0]}", :type => :failure)    
      site.save
    ensure
      yield id
    end 
  end   
  handle_asynchronously :execute
end
```

When I run this function I pass in a block:

```
 capjobs = CapJobs.new
 capjobs.execute(parameters, @site.id) do |id|
   asite = Site.find(id)
   asite.records.create!(:date => DateTime.now, :action => "Created", :type => :init)
   asite.status = "On Demo"
   asite.dev = true
   asite.save
 end
```

This works fine when run without delayed_job but when run with it I get the following error

```
2012-08-13T09:24:36-0300: [Worker(delayed_job host:eagle pid:12089)] SitesHelper::CapJobs#execute_without_delay failed with LocalJumpError: no block given (yield) - 0 failed attempts
2012-08-13T09:24:36-0300: [Worker(delayed_job host:eagle pid:12089)] PERMANENTLY removing SitesHelper::CapJobs#execute_without_delay because of 1 consecutive failures.
2012-08-13T09:24:36-0300: [Worker(delayed_job host:eagle pid:12089)] 1 jobs processed at 0.0572 j/s, 1 failed ...
```

It seems not to pick up the block that was passed in. Is this not the correct way of doing this or should I find a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method of doing this. It is kind of hacky but works well. I found [this article](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz38.html) that talks about creating a SerializableProc class. If I pass this to the function then everything works great.

Answer (score 11):

delayed_job works by saving your jobs into a data store (most often your primary database) and then loading the jobs out of this data store in a background process, where it is handled/executed.

To save a job into the database, delayed_job needs to somehow save what method to call on which object with what arguments. This is done by serializing everything into a string (delayed_job uses *yaml* for that). Unfortunately, blocks cannot be serialized. So the background worker does not know about the block argument and calls the method without it. This results in the `LocalJumpError` when the method is trying to yield to the block.

Answer (score 0):

Most people would treat this as an abstraction problem.

The proc code is probably not changing from run-to-run (except vars) and so you should make the block code into a class or instance method.  Pass the name of that method, and then call it in your `execute` method, like

`@some_data = CapJobs.send( target_method )`

or perhaps-better-even

`@some_data = DomainSpecificModel.send( target_method )`